# How to do PHP explode(", "), list(), foreach() in Java style

Tags: java, php

I have PHP code and i am translating it to Java, but how do we do PHP like explode(), list(), foreach() with Java? Following PHP code are my example problems:

```
1. PHP:
  /** 
   * @return: Array
   */
    public function parse($digest) 
    {
      $array = array();
      $parts = explode(", ", $digest);

      foreach ($parts as $x) 
      {
       $bits = explode("=", $x);
       $data[$bits[0]] = str_replace('"','', $bits[1]);
      }

      return $array;
    }

Java (updated):
  private String[] parse(String digest)
  {
    Map<String,String> array = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] parts = digest.split(", ");

    for (String x:parts)
    {
      String[] bits = x.split("=");
      array.put(bits[0], bits[1].replace( '"','' )); // later will apply regex
    }

    return array; // incompatible types
  }



2. PHP:
  /** 
   * @return: String
   */
  public function response($text, $user, $pass, $httpmethod, $uri) 
  {        
      list($dummy_digest, $value) = split(' ', $text, 2);    
      $x = $this->parse($value);

      $realm = $x['realm'];
      if ($x['qop'] == 'auth') 
      {
        ...
      }

      $base  = "{$realm}, {$x['realm']}";
      //"Digest username="1", realm="1", nonce="xxxxxx", uri="abc", response="abc", qop="auth", algorithm="MD5", cnonce="", nc="1"";
      return $base;

  }


Java problem:
   public String response(String text, String user, String pass, String httpmethod, String uri)
   {  
      // how to do such list() like php?
      return "Digest username="1", realm="1", nonce="xxxxxx", uri="abc", response="abc", qop="auth", algorithm="MD5", cnonce="", nc="1"";
   }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Zend Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's pretty much the same going to java, you could parse the data with:

```
Map<String, String> key_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] parts_of_string = "var=test, var2=test2".split(", ");
for(String part : parts_of_string) {
    String[] key_and_value_parts = part.split("=");
    key_map.put(key_and_value_parts[0], key_and_value_parts[1]);
    System.out.println(key_and_value_parts[0] + " <-> " + key_and_value_parts[1]);
}
```

Update (Second Method):

Java does not handle arrays quite the same as PHP. Where php can refrence a object in array by using a string like $array["my_var"] , Java can only reference by their index in the array. So you will need to use a map, this allows you to map a certain key to a value. You could parse the text like so:

```
private static Map<String, String> parse(String digest) {
    String[] parts = digest.split(", ");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String x : parts) {
        String[] bits = x.split("=");

        //Remove "'s here if you want to keep them in the string

        map.put(bits[0], bits[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

You can then access any information given by this map by using the method get on it. You will then specify the key you want and the map will return the value associated with that key. Be sure to use .containsKey to check if the Ma contains the key you are looking for.

So when you have parsed your information with the previous function you can then access the values by using this for example:

```
Map<String, String> parsed_map = parse("A realm=\"1234\", B=\"3434df323423423\", C=\"300.00\", D=\"loopback\"'");
String info = parsed_map.get("B");
System.out.println(info);
```

Hope that helps, else ask away :D

**PS: I haven't actually tested this just be sure to check that it runs as expected.**

Comment: Thanks, second method i have 1) $string = 'A realm="1234", B="3434df323423423", C="300.00", D="loopback"'; 2) it goes to a method parse('realm="1234" ....'); 3) Then i have array to get a value like $result['realm'] 4) it has 1234 value and then i use it to make a final string.

Comment: Hi, you could just split it again and then loop through each key and value. Then split the keys and values and add them to a Map. You will just need to remove the "'s from the value. This might be a inefficient method, maybe try Regular Expressions to filter it out with less actual code http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Comment: thanks, i updated the second method above, please have a look, how you do such in java?

Answer (score 2):

Explode
 - StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(String str, char separatorChar)

foreach is just written differently
 - for(String s : array)

I don't think there is any equivalent in Java for list, I don't think it'd be possible to write one either as all variables in Java are "pass by value".

Comment: foreach for list looks **the same** as for arrays `for(ClassOfItem item : NameOfList){ item.method(); }`

Comment: What exactly is the same about foreach($array AS $key => $value) and for(Object obj : array). They're written differently.

Comment: i was refering to foreach for arrays in Java and foreach for lists in Java - you wrote about arrays only, implementation for lists looks the same :)

Comment: and `foreach($array AS $key => $value)` is similar to `Map< key, val >` in Java :)

Answer (score 0):

example `foreach()` in Java inside of (just as sample) `clone()` method (with deep cloning - prototype design-pattern)

```
public class Order {

private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

public Order clone() {
    Order newOrder = new Order();
    for (Item originalItem : this.items) {
        Item newItem = new Item();
        newItem.setPrice(originalItem.getPrice());
        newOrder.items.add(newItem);
    }
    return newOrder;
}
```

it should be realy clear now, how to use foreach,
hope it helps